# Use of Classes and Objects as wrappers for reducing the number of imports in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, javascript-objects, es6-class

In my React project, I have a pretty good number of items with their respective actions:

```
/user/edit/:id
/users/search
....
/group/view/:id
/group/edit/:id
/groups/search/
```

when defining the Routes (I am using React Router) I find myself importing a lot of constants and almost the same React Components across the routes files of each item:

```
import {USER_VIEW_CONSTS,USER_EDIT_CONSTS} from '....'
import {ItemViewContainer} from '...'
import {ItemEditContainer} from '...'

<Route path={`${URL_USER}${URL_SEGMENT_VIEW}:id } render={props => <ItemViewContainer {...{...props, itemConsts:USER_VIEW_CONSTS}} />
<Route path={`${URL_USER}${URL_SEGMENT_EDIT}:id } render={props => <ItemEditContainer {...{...props, itemConsts:USER_EDIT_CONSTS}} />
.....
import {GROUP_VIEW_CONSTS,GROUP_EDIT_CONSTS} from '....'
import {ItemViewContainer} from '...'
import {ItemEditContainer} from '...'

<Route path={`${URL_GROUP}${URL_SEGMENT_VIEW}:id } render={props => <ItemViewContainer {...{...props, itemConsts:GROUP_VIEW_CONSTS}} />
<Route path={`${URL_GROUP}${URL_SEGMENT_EDIT}:id } render={props => <ItemEditContainer {...{...props, itemConsts:GROUP_EDIT_CONSTS}} />
```

I have just realised that may be I can take advantage of javascript Classes for wrapping the Constans ant the React.components I am using in each route file of each item (user,group...):

```
import CustomReactClassWithAllContainersAsMethods from '....'
import userConstsWrappedInObjectAsProps from ''


const CustomReactObjectWithAllContainerForEachRoute = new CustomReactClassWithAllContainersAsMethods(userConstsWrappedInObjectAsProps);

<Route path={`${userConstsWrappedInObjectAsProps.urlView}:id } render={CustomReactObjectWithAllContainerForEachRoute.viewItem} />
<Route path={`${userConstsWrappedInObjectAsProps.urlEdit}:id } render={CustomReactObjectWithAllContainerForEachRoute.editItem} />
```

There, my **CustomReactClassWithAllContainersAsMethods** and my **userConstsWrappedInObjectAsProps**:

```
class CustomReactClassWithAllContainersAsMethods {

constructor(itemProps){
this.itemProps = itemProps;
}

viewItem() => props =>  <ItemViewContainer {...{...props,itemConsts:this.itemProps}}
editItem() => props =>  <ItemEditContainer {...{...props,itemConsts:this.itemProps}}

}
```

So is not this second class approach cleaner and better? I have only made two imports and I can have the logic centralized. The reason why I have my doubts is that I have not found in the internet a single case of React.Components wrapped as methods in a custom javascript class... Is it because it is very expensive in term of resources?

The same applies in the case of the Constants, would not be better to import a single object with the constants as props?

I have not found any policies regarding this issues in the best practices suggestions I have come to read...

Thank you for your time and apologies for the length.

Comment: All of the concepts you're leveraging inside the class can easily be done with a POJO + constants in the same file. Minimal overhead and imo easier to reason

Comment: Thanks @Andrew!! so I get that there is nothing wrong with having a POJO with React.Components inside. And export this POJO with all the logic inside whenever I want it.